# Magento - display associated product option image when filtering

Tags: magento

i am using configurable products for clothing items, t -shirt, shirts, jumpers etc.

The all come in color options (which are the associated products).  Lets say for arguments sake that there are only green. black and blue options available.  Obviously with magento you can only use 1 parent image that is used throughout the store to represent that product.

Now, is it possible that when filtering by color using layered navigation, that the associated child product image is used as the thumbnail instead of the parent image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to load the product, then grab the image and output it.

To load the product by id use this code:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
```

To get the image:
    $attributes = $prod->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($prod);

```
$galleryData = $product->getData('media_gallery');

foreach ($galleryData['images'] as &$image) {
    var_dump($image);
}
```

This code will allow you to sse which image you want to use

Hope this was helpful

Pesach

Comment: This question and possibly the answer is what I am looking for for awhile now, however I am not sure I understand the answer 100%, can you be a little more specific which files need to be modified? Perhaps there is a written tutorial somewhere on how to do this?

Comment: you can load the product in any file in Magento. In other words you decide where to call this code as its pretty portable anywhere in Magento

Comment: OK first of all where did you get variable $prod from, should that be $product? Second, lets say your code returns a list of images, what do you do then? How does the code know which filter option was picked? How is the correct image displayed? I am working in template/catalog/product/list.phtml

Comment: It should be $prod. this code gives you an array with the path and image type (i.e. base, thumbnail etc) if you var_dump the array you will be able to see what it contains. to put on the list page just create a <img> tag and use the data from the array as the 'src'